Giving a Docker Container The Ability to Modify a Network Mounted SMB CIFS Volume
I have a NAS which ive mounted to an LXC Container (debian 12) running on Proxmox (privliged and nested) by creating an fstab entry. I cant give any other user ownership of the files or directories inside the volume which is hindering alot of services storing their data on my NAS.
I've tried both
//192.168.2.4/Joplin /mnt/Joplin cifs credentials=/root/.smbcreds,iocharset=utf8 0 0
(The line ive been using for my other services) and
//192.168.2.4/Joplin /mnt/Joplin cifs credentials=/root/.smbcreds,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0
Which I found somewhere (I can't find the original post).
chown and chmod dont throw any errors when run, but no changes are made (this is consistent with other posts on the topic)
Ive found alot of posts on not being able to modify the owner of the volume or the share and was wondering if the docker container (i dont really have much experience with docker and arent that sure how they run) could be running as root or be masked somehow to appear as root user to be able to have full access to the share.
Is it possible to have a docker container/docker user masked to appear as root user and have full access to the drive?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
